# Hosting dns issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, godaddy-api

I have developed a react/node.js web app and i hosted in heroku with my own domain name.
the domain name that i have added to my heroku includes www like [www.example.ca](http://www.example.ca) and in godaddy forwarding section i have added htttps://www.example.ca.

the problem is if i now open the browser and type example.ca it wont open my website. neither https://example.ca nor http://example.ca.

i can only open it through https://www.example.ca or [www.example.ca](http://www.example.ca). from some browsers it opens in http and some other https.

so confused and i couldnt find a good documentation for this. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoDaddy doesn't support alias so you will never be able to access https://example.ca nor http://example.ca. You have to use a DNS service (DNSimple or Cloudflare) which support alias or in case you want to stick with Heroku service then choose pointDNS

Here is the flow to configure a domain with pointDNS and Godaddy

1 Add pointdns add-on

2 Add all DNS records to pointdns

3 Replace GoDaddy ns by pointdns NS something like *.pointhq.com

4 Remove forwarding from GoDaddy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't add www under name.